# Google Cloud Builder - Angular CLI Firebase CLI

Tags: angular, firebase, continuous-integration, google-cloud-platform, continuous-deployment

Trying to see if I need to use two separate images for building Angular app, using Angular CLI and deploying using Firebase CLI. And also should I even build the images every time I do a build? If so should I also run a cleanup after to remove them (how)?

Current cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase', '.' ]
  dir: 'docker/firebase'
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ["push", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase"]
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/ng', '.' ]
  dir: 'docker/ng'
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ["push", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/ng"]
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['install']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['install','--prefix','functions']
- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/ng'
  args: ['build','${_NG_ENV}',"${_NG_TARGET}"]
- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase'
  args: [ 'deploy', '-P', '${_FIREBASE_ENV}', '--token', '${_FIREBASE_TOKEN}']
```

Firebase Docker

```
# use latest Node LTS (Boron)
FROM node:carbon
# install Firebase CLI
RUN npm install -g firebase-tools

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/firebase"]
```

Angular Docker

```
# use latest Node LTS 
FROM node:carbon
# install Angular CLI
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/ng"]
```

Comment: What do you mean by images? if you have the CLI for both installed, the process should be as simple as ng build and then firebase deploy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My misunderstanding was around the [entrypoints](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/create-custom-build-steps#about_the_entrypoint_field)

I was also getting an error with angular install and found a fix, so here is new dockerfile with both CLIs.

Dockerfile

```
# use latest Node LTS (Boron)
FROM node:carbon

# install Angular CLI
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli --unsafe

# install Firebase CLI
RUN npm install -g firebase-tools
```

cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase', '.' ]
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ["push", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase"]
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['install']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['install','--prefix','functions']
- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase'
  args: ['/usr/local/bin/ng','build','${_NG_ENV}',"${_NG_TARGET}"]
- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase'
  args: [ '/usr/local/bin/firebase','deploy', '-P', '${_FIREBASE_ENV}', '--token', '${_FIREBASE_TOKEN}']
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting the solution. You should expand on the first sentence to explain what was wrong. Then (and only then) you should accept your own answer so people know your problem was solved.